# I have four variable and four equations; how can I get a solution?

Tags: equation-solving

```
Solve[
  {w == x + e - Sqrt[(a/m)*(x - y - e)],
   y == z + f - Sqrt[(z + f)*(x - w + e)], 
   x == w - e + Sqrt[(a/(m - h))*(z - w - e)],
   z == y - f + Sqrt[(a/s)*(y - f)]}, 
  {w, x, y, z}] .
```

Here `w`, `x`, `y` and `z` are variables while others like `a`, `m`, `e`, `f`, s and h are constants.

Comment: You appear to be missing a comma between the list of equations and the list of variables.

Comment: What about $h$ and $s$? Are  $a,m,e,f$ real or positive? Are $w,x,y,z $ real?

Comment: everything except w,x y and z are constant values, I want solution in form of a, m, e, f, s and h.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit** Get genearal solutions for all variables with step by step procedure

Eliminate the variables {w,x,z} (takes a few minutes) and solve for y and z.

```
eqs = {w == x + e - Sqrt[(a/m)*(x - y - e)], 
       y == z + f - Sqrt[(z + f)*(x - w + e)], 
       x == w - e + Sqrt[(a/(m - h))*(z - w - e)], 
       z == y - f + Sqrt[(a/s)*(y - f)]};

eliwxz = Eliminate[eqs, {w, x, z}]

(*   a^2 h (f^2 - 2 f y + y^2) - 
 a (2 a f^2 m - 3 a e f s - a f^2 s + 
 2 a f s Sqrt[-((a (f - y))/s)] - 4 a f m y + 3 a e s y + 
 4 a f s y - 2 a s Sqrt[-((a (f - y))/s)] y + 
 6 e s^2 Sqrt[-((a (f - y))/s)] y + 
 2 f s^2 Sqrt[-((a (f - y))/s)] y + 2 a m y^2 - 3 a s y^2 + 
 3 e s^2 y^2 + f s^2 y^2 - s^2 Sqrt[-((a (f - y))/s)] y^2) == 0   *)

soly = Solve[eliwxz, y]

(*   Get five solutions, where only the first is real 
     with the parameters used by @user64494.   *)

y /. soly /. {a -> 1, e -> 1, f -> 2, h -> 3, m -> 2, s -> 3} // N

(*   {70.7936, -0.0515867 - 0.577992 I, -0.0515867 + 0.577992 I, 
      0.339962\[VeryThinSpace]- 1.04108 I, 
      0.339962\[VeryThinSpace]+ 1.04108 I}   *)

solz = Solve[eqs[[4]] /. soly[[1]], z] // Simplify

(*   To long to show here   *)

solz /. {a -> 1, e -> 1, f -> 2, h -> 3, m -> 2, s -> 3} // N

(*   {{z -> 73.5823}}   *)
```

Get general solutions for w and x from equation 2 and 3 (or 1 and 2) and insert the already found general y and z solutions.

```
solwx23 = Solve[eqs[[{2, 3}]], {w, x}] // Simplify

(*   {{w -> (-a (e - z) (f + z)^2 + (h - m) (f - y + z)^4)/(a (f + z)^2), 
       x -> ((h - m) (f - y + z)^4 + 
a (f + z)^2 (-2 e + z + Sqrt[(f - y + z)^4/(f + z)^2]))/(
a (f + z)^2)}}   *)

solwx23 /. soly[[1]] /. solz[[1]] /. {a -> 1, e -> 1, f -> 2, h -> 3, 
m -> 2, s -> 3} // N

(*   {{w -> 72.6743, x -> 71.9777}}   *)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me.

```
sol[e_, a_, m_, f_, h_, s_] := Solve[{w == x + e - Sqrt[(a/m)*(x - y - e)], 
y == z + f - Sqrt[(z + f)*(x - w + e)], x == w - e + Sqrt[(a/(m - h))*(z - w - e)],   
 z == y - f + Sqrt[(a/s)*(y - f)]} , {w, x, y, z}];
sol[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
N[%]
(*{{w -> 72.6743, x -> 71.9777, y -> 70.7936, z -> 73.5823}}*)
sol[1, 1.2, 2, 2.7, 3, 3]
(*{{w -> 78.7533, x -> 78.1137, y -> 76.8972, z -> 79.645}}*)
```

Comment: I want solution in form of a, m, e, f, s and h. Is there a way to find it?